# Storing Documents on Azure with custom metadata

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

i am trying to find the best way to implement a small site allowing the user to upload a file and then search on it.

i used azure search with blob storage.
the file is stored on the blob storage and is then gets indexed by azure search indexer - so far so good.

the problem is that i would like to add to each document some custom data like file id and other business data, this data is not part of the document. is there a way to achieve this? 
some one, suggested i use cosmos db, though i am not sure its the best way to go when it comes to documents.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there's no "right" way to answer this, aside from just enumerating all of the various database options available (which are in the dozens, or hundreds, between 1st and 3rd-party databases). You'll really need to make this decision based on your app, the type of data you're storing, etc. Your choices will be a bit more limited if you're going to target Azure Search for FTS (regular non-fulltext searching should be supported by just about any database engine / service).

Comment: what about a combination of documentDB an blob storgage? meaning metadata one the cosmos and the actual document on the blob?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep using blob storage, you can store metadata with the blobs - just add custom metadata to your blobs, add corresponding fields to the search index, and the blob indexer will pick up the metadata.